# How to set height 100% dynamically on Safari in iOS 15

Tags: css, mobile-safari, ios15

How can you prevent the bottom bar on Safari iOS 15 from making this jump, as shown on the video?

Basically, I have a drawer with the following CSS, and it has the exact same issue.

```css
.drawer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;

  width: 85%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Video link: https://streamable.com/poveau

Comment: Have you tried `height: 100vh;` instead of `100%`?

Comment: Yes. That is the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `html` and `body` (and all other parents of `.drawer`) to `height:100%` ?